# Order values within column according to values within different column by group in R

Tags: r, sorting, panel

I have the following panel data set:

```
group  i  f  r  d
1      4  8  3  3
1      9  4  5  1
1      2  2  2  2
2      5  5  3  2
2      3  9  3  3
2      9  1  3  1
```

I want to reorder column i in this data frame according to values in column d for each group. So the highest value for group 1 in column i should correspond to the highest value in column d. In the end my data.frame should look like this:

```
group  i  f  r  d
1      9  8  3  3
1      2  4  5  1
1      4  2  2  2
2      5  5  3  2
2      9  9  3  3
2      3  1  3  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## original (wrong)

You can achieve this using `dplyr` and `rank`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(i = i[rev(rank(d))])
```

## Edit

This question is actually trickier than it first seems and the original answer I posted is incorrect. The correct solution orders by `i` before subsetting by the rank of `d`. This gives OP's desired output which my previous answer did not (not paying attention!)

```r
df1 %>% group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(i = i[order(i)][rank(d)])
```

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   group [2]
#  group     i     f     r     d
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     9     8     3     3
#2     1     2     4     5     1
#3     1     4     2     2     2
#4     2     5     5     3     2
#5     2     9     9     3     3
#6     2     3     1     3     1
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `dplyr` solution.

First, group by `group`. Then get the permutation rearrangement of column `d` in a temporary new column, `ord` and use it to reorder `i`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(ord = order(d),
         i = i[ord]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-ord)
## A tibble: 6 x 5
#  group     i     f     r     d
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     9     8     3     3
#2     1     2     4     5     1
#3     1     4     2     2     2
#4     2     9     5     3     2
#5     2     5     9     3     3
#6     2     3     1     3     1
```

Comment: thank you, I accepted the other answer since it is shorter but I applied your code.

Comment: @JjBlevins This answer doesn't give your desired output if you look closely. Admittedly neither did my first attempt - see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion regarding the expected output. Here I am showing a way to get both the versions of the output.

A base R using `split` and `mapply`

```
df$i <- c(mapply(function(x, y) sort(y)[x], 
                  split(df$d, df$group), split(df$i, df$group)))

df
#  group i f r d
#1     1 9 8 3 3
#2     1 2 4 5 1
#3     1 4 2 2 2
#4     2 5 5 3 2
#5     2 9 9 3 3
#6     2 3 1 3 1
```

Or another version

```
df$i <- c(mapply(function(x, y) y[order(x)], 
                 split(df$d, df$group), split(df$i, df$group)))

df
#  group i f r d
#1     1 9 8 3 3
#2     1 2 4 5 1
#3     1 4 2 2 2
#4     2 9 5 3 2
#5     2 5 9 3 3
#6     2 3 1 3 1
```

---

We can also use `dplyr` for this :

For 1st version

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(i = sort(i)[d])
```

2nd version is already shown by @Rui using `order`

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(i = i[order(d)])
```

Comment: Your first version assumes that values in d are sequential (it will break if one of the values in `d` is changed to 4), hence why I used `rank(d)` in my solution. You're right that `sort(i)` is shorter than `i[order(i)]` as I wrote though

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, i := i[order(d)], group]
df1
#   group i f r d
#1:     1 9 8 3 3
#2:     1 2 4 5 1
#3:     1 4 2 2 2
#4:     2 9 5 3 2
#5:     2 5 9 3 3
#6:     2 3 1 3 1
```

---

If we need the second version

```
setDT(df1)[, i := sort(i)[d], group]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), i = c(4L, 9L, 
2L, 5L, 3L, 9L), f = c(8L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 1L), r = c(3L, 5L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), d = c(3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: This doesn't match OP's expected output

Comment: @Chris I find two versions in some answers.  So, I am using one of the version

Comment: yes but only one of the versions gives the correct answer based on OP's description. Not sure where two versions are coming from

Comment: @Chris In the OP's expected it is `9 2 4 5 9 3`

Comment: Yes I agree hence my first comment.